# Prepping concrete floor

Tags: tiling

Do I need to grind down my concrete slab floor for a new bathroom before I apply membrane (HydroBan) before tiling? The slab is already quite flat, just some join compound/paint splatters.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no you do not. Clean up your joint compound if it is a bump above the surface.

HydroBan usage around fixtures:   Bonds directly to metal, PVC and ABS plumbing fixtures only.

How to use : this link does not seem to work in Firefox 57 but will work in MS Edge.

[How to use HydroBan video](https://laticrete.com/en/our-products/tile-and-stone-installation/waterproofing/hydro-ban)  : watch it and you will see them doing exactly what you are asking about with no grinding or roughing up the surface.